# Creating a parent table from child relationships

Tags: mysql, mariadb, query, group-by

I have a child relationship table as

```
CREATE TABLE ItemRelationships
(
Item1 int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
Item2 int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
INDEX(Item2),
FOREIGN KEY(Item1) REFERENCES Items(ItemID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY(Item2) REFERENCES Items(ItemID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
PRIMARY KEY(Item1,Item2)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

for a list of items:

```
CREATE TABLE Items
(
ItemID int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Title varchar(255),
ParentID int(11) unsigned,
INDEX(ParentID),
PRIMARY KEY(ItemID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

If there is a relationship between `Item1` and `Item2`, they both belong to the same parent.

But I do not have the Parent yet. How can I create unique `ParentID`s from the relationship table as

```
CREATE TABLE Parents
(
ParentID int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(ParentID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

And then update `ParentID` in the table `Items`.

Comment: We might be able to help you better if you provided the specific nouns rather than generic ones like "parent" and "item".  I don't have a picture of what the ultimate structure should look, and who.  As stated, it feels "overconstrained".

Comment: @RickJames I couldn't find an analogy. They are indeed random items. Something like a list of products. If two are similar, they belong to a category. The problem is that in a list of products, we have named categories (e.g., books), but here, the parent/category is unnamed (just a group of similar items).

Comment: What if item1 and item2 are related, plus item2 and item3 are related -- does this mean that all 3 have the same "parent"?

Comment: @RickJames sure all three belongs to the same parent. See it this way, the relationship table shows if two items are identical. If item2 is item1 and item3 is item2, then item1 and item3 are evidently identical.

Comment: If i1=i2 and i3=i4 and i2=i3, deriving the single common parent is tricky.  You might set p1 for i1 and i2, then p2 for i3 and i4, then find there is a problem when you get to the last item matchup.

Answer (score 0):

- `ItemRelationships` is a "many-to-many" relationship.
- `ChildMap` is not indexed correctly.  It probably needs:

  ```
  PRIMARY KEY(ItemID),
  INDEX(ParentID, ItemID)
  ```
- Do you already have the `Parent` for the pair of children?  That is, are you looking for an `UPDATE` or for an `INSERT`?
- If you get `ParentID` set, do you still need `ItemRelationships`?  (It is easy to get "all children".)

Comment: you're absolutely right. The index of `ChildMap` is incorrect. In fact, `ChildMap` is redundant because it is a one-to-many relationship, and I can replace it with `Items` table. I updated the question to clarify the issue.